# non-EEA national with Dutch Resident Permit

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I am a non EEA national with Dutch Resident Permit. I am thinking of exploring job opportunities in UK.

1. Would my current status of Dutch RP permit me to work in UK. If no, what are the procedures that I need to complete to obtain a WP of UK.
2. Would I be able to take up remote working of a company based out of UK and travel to UK once in 15 days.

Answer (score 1):

Q1 No, a Dutch residence permit does not allow you to work in the UK. The procedures to obtain a work permit depend on your personal circumstances; typically you need a job offer with sponsorship from an employer in the UK. Further information is available here https://www.gov.uk/browse/visas-immigration/work-visas

Q2 No, receiving income from a UK source is not allowed if you travel to the UK as a visitor. https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules